# замена всех вхождений подстроки в строке

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

моя программа получает од пользователя три строчки.
первая - строка01, в которой нужно найти все вхождения строки02 и заменить их на строку03
вторая - строка02
третья - строка03
пример:

```
str_01 = abab
str_02 = a
str_03 = EEE
result = EEEbEEEb
```

то есть, в строке `abab` нужно все `a` заменить на `EEE`
.
при таких данных все работает отлично, но когда я пишу следующие данные:

```
str_01 = abab
str_02 = a
str_03 = aa
result = бесконечный цикл
```

почему так происходит?

```
std::string str_01, str_02, str_03, sub_str;
int counter_sub = 0, position;
short no_sub = 0;
std::cout << "enter str: ";
getline(std::cin, str_01);
std::cout << "sub str: ";
getline(std::cin, str_02);
std::cout << "change str: ";
getline(std::cin, str_03);
for (int i = 0; i < str_01.length(); i++) {
    if (str_01[i] == str_02[counter_sub]) {
        sub_str.insert(counter_sub, 1, str_01[i]);
        counter_sub++;
        if (sub_str.length() == str_02.length()) {
            position = i - sub_str.length() + 1;
            str_01.erase(position, sub_str.length());
            str_01.insert(position, str_03);
            no_sub = 1;
            i -= sub_str.length();
        }
    } else {
        sub_str = "";
        counter_sub = 0;
    }
}
if (no_sub == 0) {
    std::cout << "no search sub str\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "result = " << str_01 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Продолжайте поиск с места окончания вставленной строки. Или собирайте новую строку в новом месте. Впрочем, терзают меня смутные сомнения :), что у вас вообще все работает в других случаях...

Comment: мне странно то, что если я хочу заменить `a` -> `aa` то не работает, а если `b` -> `aa` то все работает

Comment: Просто добавьте ещё одну строку для результата. И в неё копируйте либо символ исходной строки, либо строку-заменитель. Тогда всё будет работать. При этом можно не перебирать символы по одному, а сделать поиск подстроки в строке и копировать блоками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понятно почему так просиходит.

Вы берете строку `abab`, меняете в ней первую `a` на `aa` - получается строка `aabab`.

И в этом месте Ваш прелестный алгоритм даёт сбой: вы видите в "следующей позиции" ту букву `a`, которая явилась результатом замены....

ну, понятно, что Вы уйдёте в бесконечный цикл.

Избавиться от этого довольно просто: нужно *сначала* наметить в строке те места, в котоорых надо произвести замену, а *вторым шагом* уже *сделать* замену.

Тогда у Вас результат замены никак не будет влиять на процесс.

Грубо говоря, исходная строка никогда не "смешивается логически" с результатом.

"мне странно то, что если я хочу заменить a -> aa то не работает, а если b -> aa то все работает" - тот удивительный случай, когда всё само чинится. Так как при замене `b` на `aa` у Вас не прооисходит увеличения в строке кол-ва тех символов, для которых происходт замена - то Вашему алгоритму наплевать на то, что строка изменилась.

Вот если бы при замене `a` -> `aa` всё ломалось, а при замене `b` -> `bb` - работало - вот это был бы номер!

Comment: 'нужно сначала наметить в строке те места, в котоорых надо произвести замену, а вторым шагом уже сделать замену' - вы имеете ввиду при первом прохождении по строке записать все места, а потом еще раз пройтись по строке но уже заменить? просто я хотел бы сразу все делать(нашел - заменил)

Comment: можно и так, как Вы хотите, но принципиальным является момент: не делать замену в строке, а создавать новую строку, и в неё переписывать содержимое из старой, на ходу меняя некотрые части. Именно заменой  в текущей строке объясняются ошибки, из за котрых написан вопрос.

Comment: подумал еще и все таки сделал как хотел (_менять исходную строку на ходу, без создавания нового и запоминания чего либо_). Все заключалось в тому что бы за каждым изменением исходной строки правильно передвигать `i` итератор, с помощью которого я передвигають по ней. Если кратко: то у меня в коде написано `i -= sub_str.length();`. А значение этой переменной должно быть равно разнице между искаемой подстрокой и строкой для замены, то есть `i -= sub_str.length() - change_str.length();` В суме то еще в `position`нужно отнимать '1', а не добавлять. В общем даже удалось сократить код к 14 строчкам.

Comment: Вы тогда можете написать свой ответ на свой вопрос, это будет поучительно для других, и будет плюсом к Вашему рейтингу

Answer (score 2):

А вы не хотите, раз уж используете `string`, воспользоваться его возможностями?

```
for(size_t pos = 0;(pos = str_01.find(str_02,pos)) != str_01.npos;pos += str_03.length())
    str_01 = str_01.replace(pos,str_02.length(),str_03);
```

Этого вполне достаточно...

Comment: вот это я понимаю! Harry пришел и просто помог! Спасибо! Автор воопроса, думаю, имеет смысл именно этот ответ пометить как "принятый"

Comment: мой вопрос был задан что бы решить проблему в моем (профессиональном) алгоритме, и этот ответ никак не относится к теме вопроса.

Comment: Простите, что посмел высказать свое мнение профессионалу и предложил код в 2 строки вместо 16...

Comment: Tyше... Коллеги, мы все можем быть чуть более снисходительны к достоинствам друг друга :-) Но предложение Harry - это и правда "сделано, прямо как надо!" 
я бы этот код даже высек в граните, если бы мне вовремя попалась подходящая глыба! (ну, и если Harry не решит в коде еще что нибудь улучшить :-) )